# Listview from DB

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to get some data from a DB and display in a listview, but they logcat say Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cotizacionescolumna);
    lvCotizacion = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_cotizaciones);
    list_cotizaciones = new ArrayList<String>();
    llenarLista();
    eventos();
}

public void llenarLista(){

        CotiCadSqlite db = new CotiCadSqlite(CotizacionesColumnnaActivity.this);
        Cursor c = db.obtenerNombresColumna();

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                columna = c.getString(1);
                list_cotizaciones.add(columna);
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_cotizaciones);
        lvCotizacion.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: please add database query.

Comment: can you post the `obrenerNombresColumna()`

Comment: c.getString(1); seems this line is wrong, you need to get the index before getString

Comment: public Cursor obtenerNombresColumna() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT nombre FROM TB_COLUMNA", null);
    }

Comment: writing code in Spanish (or whatever it is), and then asking for help in the English-speaking community is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 columna = c.getString(1);
```

to

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(1))
```

as well

```
if (null != c) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //your code goes here


                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
```

Comment: I tried with c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(1)) but the method need a string not an int

Comment: yeah this will give string value only.  what you mean by 1 on that line, you must pass the column name in that place instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
      Cursor c = helper.DatabaseMethod();// retrive data
                    c.moveToFirst();
                          while (c.isAfterLast() == false) 
         {

         String   dataSaved = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.KEY_EMAIL));//your column index name       
   list_cotizaciones.add(dataSaved );

                                   c.moveToNext();
                                  }
                                  c.close();

     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_cotizaciones);
               lvCotizacion.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: DatabaseConnector helper=new DatabaseConnector(this); getting my database class

Comment: else ,try using Simple cursor adapter for getting data from db show in listview. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30573420/4447803- easy to implement